# What does the absolute value sign mean when used around the differential part of an integral?

Tags: calculus, integration, absolute-value, differential, radon-transform

The [Wikipedia entry on Radon transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radon_transform) shows an equation like the following:
$$
\int_L f(\mathbf{x})|\mathbf{dx}|.
$$
What does absolute value around $$|\mathbf{dx}|$$ mean in an integral?

I understand that for the Radon transform we want to integrate the function along the line $L$, but I don't understand the notation in the equation I listed above.

Comment: Their link to [line integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Definition) takes you *right* to its definition. How would you calculate the length of the curve $L$?

Comment: @KurtG. I think the |dx| can be (at least loosely) interpreted as a small length along the curve L.  It's not clear to me why the absolute value signs are needed.

Comment: There is no looseness whatsoever in  the definition for which Wikipedia and I provided a link. A good reason for the absolute value signs is that  there is another type of line integral that integrates a vector along  a curve ("work done"). Please google that and get familiar with it. In short: its proper notation is $\int_L\mathbf{F}\cdot d\mathbf{x}\,.$

Comment: For one thing, $|dz|$ is the natural notation in complex analysis when one wants to distinguish it from the regular $dz$ line integrals.

Comment: @KurtG. I think I understand the line integral you described for "work done," but I still don't understand why the absolute value is used in Radon transform.

Comment: If we don't know what we are doing then no notation will  tell us that. This standard [article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Line_integral#Line_integral_of_a_scalar_field) explains *both*  types of line integrals and their notation. In short: as Ninad Munshi pointed out the $|\mathbf{dx}|$ is not the only possibility (and afaik not even the most common). Can you live with $|\mathbf{dx}|=ds=\sqrt{\dot x^2+\dot y^2}\,dt\,?$